# What functionality does it makes sense to implement using Rust enums?

Tags: rust, enums

I'm having problem understanding the usefulness of Rust enums after reading *The Rust Programming Language*.

In [section 17.3, **Implementing an Object-Oriented Design Pattern**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html#trade-offs-of-the-state-pattern), we have this paragraph:

> If we were to create an alternative implementation that didn’t use the state pattern, we might instead use `match` expressions in the methods on `Post` or even in the `main` code that checks the state of the post and changes behavior in those places. That would mean we would have to look in several places to understand all the implications of a post being in the published state! This would only increase the more states we added: each of those `match` expressions would need another arm.

I agree completely. It would be very bad to use enums in this case because of the reasons outlined. Yet, using enums was my first thought of a more idiomatic implementation. Later in the same section, the book introduces the concept of encoding the state of the objects using types, via variable shadowing.

It's my understanding that Rust enums can contain complex data structures, and different variants of the same `enum` can contain different types.

What is a real life example of a design in which enums are the better option? I can only find fake or very simple examples in other sources.

I understand that Rust uses enums for things like `Result` and `Option`, but those are very simple uses. I was thinking of some functionality with a more complex behavior.

This turned out to be a somewhat open ended question, but I could not find a useful response after searching Google. I'm free to change this question to a more closed version if someone could be so kind as to help me rephrase it.

Comment: enums == runtime information. types == compile time information

Comment: A common usage is in performance critical code where a container should hold several types. By using for example a vector of of Enums, the items are in close proximity in memory, which usually translates to better performance. The other option is to use Box or some other smart reference type and dynamic traits, but then the items can be scattered in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fundamental trade-off between these choices in a broad sense has a name: "[the expression problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem)". You should find plenty on Google under that name, both in general and in the context of Rust.

In the context of the question, the "problem" is to write the code in such a way that both adding a new state and adding a new operation on states does not involve modifying existing implementations.

When using a trait object, it is easy to add a state, but not an operation. To add a state, one defines a new type and implements the trait. To add an operation, naively, one adds a method to the trait but has to intrusively update the trait implementations for all states.

When using an enum for state, it is easy to add a new operation, but not a new state. To add an operation, one defines a new function. To add a new state, naively, one must intrusively modify all the existing operations to handle the new state.

If I explained this well enough, hopefully it should be clear that both will have a place. They are in a way dual to one another.

With this lens, an enum would be a better fit when the operations on the enum are expected to change more than the alternatives. For example, suppose you were trying to represent an abstract syntax tree for C++, which changes every three years. The set of types of AST nodes may not change frequently relative to the set of operations you may want to perform on AST nodes.

With that said, there are solutions to the more difficult options in both cases, but they remain somewhat more difficult. And what code must be modified may not be the primary concern.

Comment: This was very helpful. Enums make it easy to add operations and Traits make it easy to add states. The trade-offs are clear to me. Maybe the idiomatic solution used in the book should make use of enums instead? I feel it's most more likely that `Post` will receive new operations in the future than new states.